# Magento Upload Modules

Tags: magento

Does anybody know of any modules that can import configurable products AS WELL as creating attribute options (if they don't exist) on upload.

I've found two modules that can do either of these but not both.. I don't mind paying for a module etc.

Answer (score -2):

Please have a look at [MageSyncAPI](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magesyncapi.html), which can help you with the import of Configurable Products into your Magento. Regarding the creation of attribute options (if they don't exist) on upload, I believe that they will be providing this feature in their extension. However, if they don't then you will need to ask them to support this feature also.

Hope it helps.